# Why is my code unreachable when command is used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

from `let answer = message.content` to `Hiring status: ${message.content}`) code is unreachable
here is the full code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "status",
  category: "status check",
  description: "Checks the status of the pm manager.",
  aliases: [],
  usage: "status",
  userperms: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
  botperms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    return message.channel.send(`what is your hiring status?`);
    let answer = message.content;
    return message.channel.send(`Status of ${message.author}:\n` + `Hiring status: ${message.content}`);
  },
};
```

Comment: You return the result of message.channel.send(...). Anything after a return statement in a function is not executed.

Comment: I suggest to learn the basics of programming first before diving into more complex programming exercises like here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `return` from `run` function.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'status',
    category: 'status check',
    description: 'Checks the status of the pm manager.',
    aliases: [],
    usage: 'status',
    userperms: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.channel.send(`what is your hiring status?`)
        let answer = message.content
        message.channel.send(`Status of ${message.author}:\n` +
        `Hiring status: ${message.content}`)
    }
}
```